# How do I repeat a set of tests across modules with different dependencies?

Tags: java, testing, gradle

I'm starting a project where a "core" module will define a set of common interfaces and other modules implement those interfaces using different libraries on the back end. It's very similar to SLF4J, where the API module describes all the operations you can use and the binding modules implement those operations in various logging frameworks like Log4j, java.util logging, and Logback. To use it, you depend on the API module and one of the binding modules, and you only ever interact with the API.

My problem lies in testing. Since the API expresses all possible operations and every binding module should behave the same way, I want to write one set of tests that describes the expected behavior and run the same tests against every binding module. How should I organize things to get this to work without a lot of repeated effort?

This is a Java project with plenty of Groovy, and I plan to build it with Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

i've done this sort of thing with JUnit before. what i did was define a set of abstract test classes with all the logic:

```
public abstract AbstractTestBase {
    protected abstract CommonInterface getInstance(); //for subclasses to implement

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
       CommonInterface instance = getInstance();
       //test instance
    }
}
```

and then concrete subclasses are usually just tiny classes that return the concrete implementation to be tested:

```
public class TestSomeImplementation extends AbstractTestBase {
    protected CommonInterface getInstance() {
        return new SomeImplementation();
    }
}
```

on some i've added specific tests for specific implementations, but in your case i understand you wont need to.

Comment: I've considered this approach, but it still means if I have 10 test classes and 10 modules to test, I have to create 100 of those "tiny classes", which seems like needless work. Then if I add a new test class, I also have to remember to add a new subclass to each module. To me, this sounds like the least desirable approach to be used only as a last resort.

Comment: @RyanStewart - i dont know gradle, but if this was maven you could try pulling the test configuration up to a common parent (where the 10 generic test classes would be listed) and then have each test class figure out under what module its currently running, locate the correct implementation to test (possible if you use any mechanism that lists them, like the service provider API) and test it. this, however complicates the build configuration immensley and imposes a few limitations on the project structure as well. also, i dont even know if such a thing is possible for gradle

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the binding mechanism. If multiple bindings can co-exist, you can tackle the problem on the test level, by writing a data-driven test that runs the same test class/method for each binding. (Details on how to achieve this depend on the test framework in use.) If bindings cannot co-exist, you can tackle the problem on the build level. For example, you could create ten `Test` tasks which would be configured identically except for the implementation Jar on their class path.

Comment: In my mind, the bindings won't coexist. Certainly some of the binding modules will introduce classpath conflicts. Having been working out the build details overall, I've already started thinking along the lines of defining the tests at the build level. I'm going to explore that idea further.